# OSX Django Project makemigrations error: Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, pycharm

Python 2.7.10

System: Mac OS Sierre

I've installed mysql-python, and the connection to local mysql was all good.
But in the PyCharm manage.py command line, when I tried to run makemigrations command, the following error message came up:

```
bash -cl "/Users/alan/.virtualenvs/testvir/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py makemigrations /Users/alan/PycharmProjects/djangoStart"

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

I'm wondering if anyone has a fix on this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was the MySQL issue, I ended up [remove all MySQL files](https://gist.github.com/vitorbritto/0555879fe4414d18569d):

and downloaded the installation file from [MySQL official site](http://cdn.mysql.com//Downloads/MySQL-5.6/mysql-5.6.35-macos10.12-x86_64.dmg)(MySQL 5.7 uses libmysqlclient.20.dylib instead of libmysqlclient.18.dylib, so I picked MySQL 5.6)
And you may need to create a symlink to make it work:

```
ln -s /usr/local/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib  /usr/local/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib
```